# Untar function produces error code 1 when trying to untar shiny web app files

Tags: r, shiny, tar

We could use a refresher on how to untar shiny web app files that have been downloaded from the account.

[image]

I get this error.

```
Warning message:
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '/Users/filepath/Downloads/ad2007308f644d078ec59ce84d31ce7f .tar'
In untar("/Users/filepath/Downloads/ad2007308f644d078ec59ce84d31ce7f.tar",  :
  ‘/usr/bin/tar -xf '/Users/filepath/Downloads/ad2007308f644d078ec59ce84d31ce7f.tar' -C '/Users/new/desired/file/path'’ returned error code 1
```

In the past, this appears to work in terms of generating a download. But now I seem to be getting stuck on that part. Are there any packages I need to load? Any differences between mac and PC? (I just bought a new mac). Anything about the untar function that Im not considering?

Comment: are you sure you are trying to untar a `tarball` ?

Comment: yeah it was working but now it does not.